# UIDatePicker display seconds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uidatepicker, seconds

Is there any chance to display seconds in uidatepicker? I don't really see reference for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do this with UIDatePicker, but you can make your own using [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html). Just be aware that by doing this you'll lose the locality-aware features of UIDatePicker.